# Using XSLT to process an HTML page and move a DIV from one place to another

Tags: xslt

I have a HTML page (fully valid) that is post-processed by XSLT.

Let's say the relevant section of code looks like this:

```
<div id="content"> ... </div>
...
<div id="announcement"> ... </div>
```

The XSLT needs to transform it to look like this:

```
<div id="content"> <div id="announcement"> ... </div> ... </div>
```

Any ideas? I'm stuck.

**Edit**: Indicated that `<div id="content">` and `<div id="announcement">` are separated by other code.

Comment: Is your HTML page an XHTML page?

Comment: Not all valid HTML is valid XHTML. What's the DTD at the top of the document?

Comment: I'm using an HTML5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 2):

If the `announcement` div *directly follows* the `content` div, use:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@id='content' and following-sibling::div[1][@id='announcement']">
  <!-- copy the content div and its attributes -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <!-- now make a copy of the directly following announcement div -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::div[1][@id='announcement']" />
    <!-- process the rest of the contents -->
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- the empty template mutes an announcement div that follows a content div -->
<xsl:template match="div[@id='announcement' and preceding-sibling::div[1][@id='content']" />
```

The above is specific enough not to touch any other divs that might be in your document. If your situation allows, you can make it simpler/less specific to increase readability.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't directly follow the content div; however, it should always be in the same place (relative to the content div). Perhaps I can modify your suggested code? Thank you!

Comment: @Dave: Sure, should not be too hard. The code I supplied takes the first following div if it has the id "announcement". You can reverse it `following-sibling::div[@id='announcement'][1]` or work with the `following::` axis and see where that gets you.